# How to get friends' id via Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook

I've got a list of user's phone contacts. When user clicks on the contact I want my app publish on his wall. I will use feed dialog with parameter "TO". But for that I need list of Facebook friend's id and name. Then I'll select sutable id with the help of the name.

I've already make authorization and tried to make id request in three ways. Here is the first:

```
if(session.getState().isOpened()){
        Log.i(TAG, "Creating request");
        Request friendRequest = new Request(session, "/me/taggable_friends", null,  HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Complete");
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


        Log.i(TAG, "Sending request");
        friendRequest.executeAsync();
    }
```

And the second:

```
Request friendRequest = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(session,
                new Request.GraphUserListCallback(){
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Request successful");
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

And the third:

```
Log.i(TAG, "Creating request");
        Request friendRequest =  new Request(session, "/me/friends", null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Complete");
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
        );

        Log.i(TAG, "Sending request");
        friendRequest.executeAsync();
```

All of them returns nothing. onComplited void doesn't start. Session permissions:

```
[public_profile, user_likes, user_friends, user_status]
```

Where is my mistake? Or is there any other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`taggable_friends` is for tagging friends only, you are not supposed to use it for anything else and you would not get it approved in the review process. The only serious/allowed way for you is to use `/me/friends`, but keep in mind that you will only get friends who authorized your App too. Which means that you can only use friends who authorized your App for the "to" parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've added what to adviced me as the third way. But progressDialog doesn't dissapere. It means that onComleted doesn't start. Why?

Comment: i am not experienced enough with the android stuff to answer that question in a serious way, but why would you need user_likes, public_profile and user_status? user_friends is all you need.

Comment: They are included to every login by default. I've not asked for them @luschn

Comment: that´s can´t be, even with an old v1.0 app created before april 2014, user_status and user_likes would not be included by default. in a v2.x app all those permissions are not included by default and you have to ask for them.

Comment: But I do not ask for them. I've just open active session and ask for permissions and they already were there. Maybe it is magic :)