# Facebook SDK 3.22 (android) - Ways of sharing

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I use Facebook SDK 3.22 for Android. I want my app to do the following:

1. Post content on user's wall
2. Share content with user's friend

For the 1st point I've decided to use feed dialog. So I've made logging in and dialog. It works perefect. No questions about this.

But I confused with the 2nd. At first, I also wanted to use feed diolog with parameter "TO" but with the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986505/how-to-get-friends-id-via-facebook/27986822#27986822) 
I undersand that I need to invite friend befor posting on it's wall. So I've made invite dialog. But with the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003124/facebook-sdk-wrong-id-while-invating-friends?noredirect=1#comment44396178_28003124) I understand that I can't do even this.

Could you explain to me how can I share content with friend.

**P.S** My app is not a game and does not have a canvas version. It has only basic permissions

Comment: @DarylGill I have tried to use feed dialog but it requires friends id. I can get only ids of friends that use my app. Also i've tried to invite but it is for games only. I want to know the other solutions of sharing content with friends. Just names. It will be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to post only to the user's wall throw the Feed dialod or Share dialog (if Facebook is installed). You can only send private messages to user's friends